# Using an Analyzer within a custom FieldBridge

Tags: hibernate-search, analyzer

I have a List getter method that I want to index (tokenized) into a number of fields.

I have a FieldBridge implementation that iterates over the list and indexes each string into a field with the index appended to the field name to give a different name for each.

I have two different Analyzer implementations (CaseSensitiveNGramAnalyzer and CaseInsensitiveNGramAnalyzer) that I want to use with this FieldBridge (to make a case-sensitive and a case-insensitive index of the field).

This is the FieldBridge I want to apply the Analyzers to:

```
public class StringListBridge implements FieldBridge
{

   @Override
   public void set(String name, Object value, Document luceneDocument, LuceneOptions luceneOptions)
   {
      List<String> strings = (List<String>) value;
      for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++)
      {
         addStringField(name + 1, strings.get(i), luceneDocument, luceneOptions);
      }
   }

   private void addStringField(String fieldName, String fieldValue, Document luceneDocument, LuceneOptions luceneOptions)
   {
      Field field = new Field(fieldName, fieldValue, luceneOptions.getStore(), luceneOptions.getIndex(), luceneOptions.getTermVector());
      field.setBoost(luceneOptions.getBoost());
      luceneDocument.add(field);
   }
}
```

- **Is it possible to apply an Analyzer to a field that uses a FieldBridge?**
- **If so, can this be done with annotations, or does it have to be done programatically?**
- **If the latter, can I inject the Analyzer as a parameter?**

I am thinking along the lines of the following, but am not at all familiar with field token streams etc.:

```
   private void addStringField(String fieldName, String fieldValue, Document luceneDocument, LuceneOptions luceneOptions)
   {
      Field field = new Field(fieldName, fieldValue, luceneOptions.getStore(), luceneOptions.getIndex(), luceneOptions.getTermVector());
      field.setBoost(luceneOptions.getBoost());
      try
      {
         field.setTokenStream(new CaseSensitiveNGramAnalyzer().reusableTokenStream(fieldName, new StringReader(fieldValue)));
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      luceneDocument.add(field);
   }
```

**Is this a sane approach?**

**EDIT** I have tried specifying the Analyzer and FieldBridge within a @Field annotation (without including the above analyzer code) as follows, but it appears to be using the default analyzer rather than those specified with `analyzer =` .

```
   @Fields({
      @Field(name="content-nocase",
             index = Index.TOKENIZED,
             analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = CaseInsensitiveNgramAnalyzer.class),
             bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = StringListBridge.class)),
      @Field(name = "content-case",
             index = Index.TOKENIZED,
             analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = CaseSensitiveNgramAnalyzer.class),
             bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = StringListBridge.class)),
   })
   public List<String> getContents()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working. Hibernate Search appears not to use the specified Analyzer when both `analyzer =` and `bridge =` are specified, at least if the specified bridge creates multiple fields.

Manually passing the TokenStream from the desired analyzer to the generated Fields in the bridge got me the expected result:

```
   private void addStringField(String fieldName, String fieldValue, Document luceneDocument, LuceneOptions luceneOptions)
   {
      Field field = new Field(fieldName, fieldValue, luceneOptions.getStore(), luceneOptions.getIndex(), luceneOptions.getTermVector());
      field.setBoost(luceneOptions.getBoost());

      // manually apply token stream from analyzer, as hibernate search does not
      // apply the specified analyzer properly
      try
      {
         field.setTokenStream(analyzer.reusableTokenStream(fieldName, new StringReader(fieldValue)));
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      luceneDocument.add(field);
   }
```

`ParameterizedBridge` is implemented to specify which analyzer to use (`analyzer` is instantiated and stored in a field before this method is called).

Comment: Can I ask how you are creating the analyzers. Programmatically or did you figure out a way to access by name the ones created with @AnalyzerDef?

Comment: @HandyManDan I haven't touched this in a long time, but it looks like I ended up instantiating them manually. Here is a relevant commit from when I was working on this, there is probably relevant info in surrounding commits, and possibly in the current versions of the modified files (our indexing has changed somewhat over the last year though): https://github.com/zanata/zanata-server/commit/e4b9970393eaf7d2cbddc43048875a897aa7f236

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I believe there is no way at present to access a named analyzer, created with AnalyzerDef, inside of the bridge implementation. This issue addresses https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1306

Answer (score 3):

The solution atm is via a custom scoped analyzer or using *@AnalyzerDiscriminator* together with *@AnalyzerDef*. This is also discussed on the Hibernate Search forum - https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1016667

Comment: There is a blog post on in.relation.to as well - http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/CustomAnalyzersForFieldsDefinedInClassOrFieldBridges

Comment: It's important to know that if you use the @AnalyzerDiscriminator approach, that the annotation is applied to the entire entity - not just the property. getAnalyzerDefinitionName is called for every field in that entity, meaning that if you have more than one analyzer for the entity, you need to look at the field param and return the correct analyzer.